# Textcat filter longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, rows, tweets

I'm trying to apply textcat filter to a dataframe but it gives me the error. How do I get rid of it?
The code is:

```
newmerged_df <- newmerged_df[textcat(newmerged_df$text) == c("english", "indonesian", "scots", "middle_frisian"),]
View(newmerged_df)
```

But it gives me warning:

```
Warning message:
In textcat(newmerged_df$text) == c("english", "indonesian",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The newmerged_df has 1,034 rows but it gives 98 which is not correct after applying texcat filter.
What to do? Help!

Comment: I think you want to use `%in%` instead of `==` here

Comment: Thanks @Esther it works :)